# Typescript import/export

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, export, undefined

After running app.ts, I was expecting to get this result :

```
{ val: 'A' } //C
{ val: 'CONSTANT'} //B
```

but, I'm getting this result:

```
{ val: 'A' } //C
{ val: undefined } //B supposed to be 'CONSTANT' ??
```

Any ideas?? thank you !

This is the complete code:

tsconfig.json

```
"target": "es6",                                     
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"module": "commonjs",
"rootDir": "./src",
"outDir": "./dist", 
"esModuleInterop": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"strict": true,    
"strictPropertyInitialization": false,
"skipLibCheck": true
```

app.ts

```
import { C } from "./second";
import { B } from "./first";

console.log(C)
console.log(B)

/**
 *  C depends on A
 *  B depends on CONSTANT
 **/
```

first.ts

```
import { CONSTANT } from "./second"
const A ={
    val: 'A'
}
const B = {
    val: CONSTANT
}
export { A, B }
```

second.ts

```
import { A } from "./first";
const CONSTANT = 'CONSTANT'
const C = {
    val: A.val
}
export { CONSTANT, C }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a cyclic dependency. `const CONSTANT = 'CONSTANT'` should be placed in a separate file

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I dont understand why it's considered as cyclic dependency while const C depends only on const A and const B depends only on const CONSTANT.

Comment: The JS engine reads files line by line.
1) app.ts -> import { C } from "./second";
2) second.ts -> import { A } from "./first";
3) import { CONSTANT } from "./second"
Here he understands that the second.ts file has already been imported earlier, so he takes it from memory, but since he has not yet read it to the end (he only counted the first line), he takes CONSTANT as undefined

Comment: Appreciate, thank you for the clarification !

Comment: It does not work for me. Simplified the case, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73594930/persistent-undefined-error-in-typescript-import-export